# Python- unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

Hey guys im new in python. I research all of the questions like mine but my english is low, and my python knowledge is  low too. So, there is the question.
Im making a calculator with python.

```
giriş = """
```

(1) topla
(2) çıkar
(3) çarp
(4) böl
(5) karesini hesapla
(6) kare kök hesapla
Çıkmak için "q" basınız.
"""
print(giriş)
anahtar = 1
while True:
    soru = input("Yapacağınız işlemin numarasını giriniz:   ")

```
if  soru == "q":
    print("Çıkılıyor...")
    break

elif  soru == "1":
    print("Toplama işlemini seçtiniz!")
    top1 = input("Bir sayı giriniz: ")
    top2 = input("diğer sayıyı giriniz: ")
    top1 = int(top1)
    top2 = int(top2)
    print("Sonucunuz:", top1 + top2)

elif soru == "2":
    print("Çıkarma işlemini seçtiniz!") 
    cik1=input("Bir sayı giriniz: ")
    cik2=input("diğer sayıyı giriniz: ")
    cik1 = int(cik1)
    cik2 = int(cik2)
    print("Sonucunuz: ", cik1 - cik2)

elif soru == "3":
    print("Çarpma işlemini seçtiniz!")
    carp1=input("Bir sayı giriniz: ")
    carp2=input("diğer sayıyı giriniz: ")
    carp1=int(carp1)
    carp2=int(carp2)
    print("Sonucunuz: ", carp1 * carp2)

elif soru == "4":
    print("Bölme işlemi seçtiniz!")
    bol1=input("Bir sayı giriniz: ")
    bol2=input("diğer sayıyı giriniz: ")
    bol1=int(bol1)
    bol2=int(bol2)
    print("Sonucunuz: ", bol1 / bol2)

 elif soru == "5": 
    print("Karesini bulmayı seçtiniz!")
    kare1=input("Karesi hesaplanacak sayıyı giriniz: ")
    kare1 = int(kare1)
    print("Sonucunuz: ", pow(kare1,2))

 elif soru == "6":
    print("Karekök bulmayı seçtiniz!" )
    karekok=input("Karekökü bulunacak sayıyı giriniz: ")
    karekok= int(karekok)
    print("Sonucunuz: ", karekok ** 0.5 )

  else:
    print("Yanlış seçim! Lütfen aşağıdakilerden birini seçiniz.", giriş)
    print("-"*30)
```

The problem is in here:

```
elif soru == "5": 
    print("Karesini bulmayı seçtiniz!")
    kare1=input("Karesi hesaplanacak sayıyı giriniz: ")
    kare1 = int(kare1)
    print("Sonucunuz: ", pow(kare1,2))
```

When i run the program, signing this code block and saying: "unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the `elif soru == "5":` line - it's indented by one space (as opposed to the previous `elif`s which begin at the start of the line). The error message was trying to tell you exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to fix your indentation this way:

```
# ...    

elif soru == "4":
    print("Bölme işlemi seçtiniz!")
    bol1=input("Bir sayı giriniz: ")
    bol2=input("diğer sayıyı giriniz: ")
    bol1=int(bol1)
    bol2=int(bol2)
    print("Sonucunuz: ", bol1 / bol2)

# remove the spaces before 'elif'
elif soru == "5":
    print("Karesini bulmayı seçtiniz!")
    kare1=input("Karesi hesaplanacak sayıyı giriniz: ")
    kare1 = int(kare1)
    print("Sonucunuz: ", pow(kare1,2))

# remove the spaces before 'elif'
elif soru == "6":
    print("Karekök bulmayı seçtiniz!" )
    karekok=input("Karekökü bulunacak sayıyı giriniz: ")
    karekok= int(karekok)
    print("Sonucunuz: ", karekok ** 0.5 )

# remove the spaces before 'else'
else:
    print("Yanlış seçim! Lütfen aşağıdakilerden birini seçiniz.", giriş)
    print("-"*30)
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @TeomanYüksel you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

you have a space or two before that clause:

```
 elif soru == "5": 
     print("Karesini bulmayı seçtiniz!")
     kare1=input("Karesi hesaplanacak sayıyı giriniz: ")
     kare1 = int(kare1)
     print("Sonucunuz: ", pow(kare1,2))
```

when in reality it should be:

```
elif soru == "5": 
    print("Karesini bulmayı seçtiniz!")
    kare1=input("Karesi hesaplanacak sayıyı giriniz: ")
    kare1 = int(kare1)
    print("Sonucunuz: ", pow(kare1,2))
```

That should fix your problem, keep up the good work!

Comment: This is actually wrong. You need to indent the statements that follow the `elif`.

Comment: Sorry i wrote this on a tablet and the formatting was rather tricky, its been amended now.

Comment: Happens to the best, +1